# Ubuntu 16.04 not waking up after suspend on HP Elitebook 8440 (and spamming kern.log)

Tags: suspend, 16.04

This computer was perfectly happy with Linux Mint 16 for a long time.  I just upgraded it to Ubuntu 16.04, and am having 3 problems.  Any suggestions for any of them would be appreciated.

- It does not wake up after suspending.    With the kernel directly from Ubuntu 16.04, (4.4.0-22, if I read right), the fan wakes up but there's no other sign of life (black display, can't ping the machine, etc).  Following suggestions from https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1574125 that looked similar, I tried upgrading the kernel, using http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.4.9-xenial/ .   After upgrading the kernel, I can ssh to the machine after suspend&resume; but the screen is still totally black.
- Every 5 seconds, it's spamming "failed to disable graphics turbo" to kern.log
- Also - the machine crashes occasionally playing online movies, and playing .   It seems to just abruptly turn off, and I can't find where to look for meaningful crash information.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After an

> apt-get update; apt-get upgrade; apt-get dist-upgrade

yesterday, suspend started working again.

And booting from the default kernel stopped the "failed to disable graphics turbo" messages.

And I haven't had any crashes since then either --- so I think all is well again.

**TL/DR:  'apt-get update; apt-get dist-upgrade' fixed everything**

Comment: Trying. A got a workaround today. Just lock before you leave your system. Then wake-up after suspend is working.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with Ubuntu 18.40 (final Beta) and HP EliteBook 850 G5 and the solution for me was to blacklist `amdgpu` and all the boot errors and suspend issues were gone.

How to blacklist amdgpu is described [here on Unix and Linux SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/360709/how-to-blacklist-amdgpu):

Open `blacklist.conf`, for example run

```
sudo vi /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

(if using Vi(m) press <kbd>i</kbd> and) add the text

```
blacklist amdgpu
```

save and exit (in Vi(m) press <kbd>esc</kbd> and type `:wq`)

Regenerate the initramfs:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the Hardware of the ELiteBook 840 does not support the Hibernate function under ubuntu (official HP site). Apparently there is a similar problem for the suspend function since I am facing a similar problem. The screen just will not wake up.

Answer (score 0):

At least on my case it seems that Radeon drivers and/or X is guilty. Workaround is disabling blank screen or `compiz --replace &` to restart the compiz server